# Menu mobile, alterar a cor da fonte

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu, layout-responsivo

Não consigo mudar a cor da fonte no modo mobile, ele fica branco, e se mudo o `CSS` para branco ele muda do site, segue o código do menu.

```
#advanced_menu_toggle, #advanced_menu_hide {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    line-height: 46px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    right: 0;
    top: 15%;
    color: #000000 !important;
    margin-top: -5px;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se você está aplicando a cor na tag `<a href...` do menu, é lá onde deve ser aplicado.

Contando que esse elemento da id `#advanced_menu_toggle` estiver aplicado em uma `<ul>`, seria tipo isso:

```
#advanced_menu_toggle li a {
  color: #000000;
  ...
}
```

Caso a cor altere no 'modo desktop'  também, você deve usar as media queries.